# SharePoint 2013: Search content webpart, How to filter on a contenttype and a list?

Tags: search

I have a search content webpart. I already filter on a contenttype. But this contenttype is used by 2 lists. I would like to add a extra filter for only ListA.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the path to the list you can add

```
path:urltoList contenttype:whatever
```

as query

Comment: Can I do something like this?: Path:{SiteCollection.URL}/Lists/ListA/

Comment: What type of parameter would that be? But yes the Url should look like that

Comment: I hope this tag {SiteCollection.URL} wil get the current site collection url. I dont want to add a fixed site collection url.

Comment: Should work, you might need " around the {SiteCollection.URL}/Lists/ListA/